How do I make HTML code using typescript?
I have no experience with javascript and typescript. When I used PHP I made a navbar into a function that would echo the html code. Is this also achievable using typescript? I have made a function that returns a string of html code, but I don't know how to actually make it render the html when I call the function on my html page (if the typescript code would even be correct). My school demands that I use typescript.
export function navbar(): string {
    const menuItems: MenuItems = {
        Home: "index.html",
        About: "about.html",
        FAQ: "faq.html",
        Contact: "contact.html",
    };
    let htmlCode: string = "<nav><ul>";

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(menuItems)) {
        htmlCode += `<li><a src="${key}">${value}</a></li>`;
    }
    htmlCode += "</nav></ul>";

    return htmlCode;
}

edit:
I now have tried this
type MenuItems = {
    [key: string]: string;
};

export function createNavbar(): void {
    const navigation: HTMLElement = document.createElement("nav");
    const unorderedList: HTMLUListElement = document.createElement("ul");
    const menuItems: MenuItems = {
        Home: "index.html",
        About: "about.html",
        FAQ: "faq.html",
        Contact: "contact.html",
    };

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(menuItems)) {
        const listItem: HTMLElement = document.createElement("li");
        const anchor: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");

        anchor.textContent = key;
        anchor.href = value;

        listItem.appendChild(anchor);
        unorderedList.appendChild(listItem);
    }

    navigation.appendChild(unorderedList);
    document.body.appendChild(navigation);
}

and this for my html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="../src/common.ts"></script>
    <script>createNavbar()</script>
</body>
</html>


it still does not seem to work. I've got a blank page

You're really asking how to create elements with JavaScript. The fact that you're using TypeScript is somewhat irrelevant. Then, the right way to do that is to create  actual elements, then update their properties, then insert them into the document. Creating markup strings is somewhat antipattern. I suggest that you revise your strategy to do that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement.

In this case you'd create nav, list, list item, and anchor elements. You'd then append the anchor to the list item, the list item to the list, and so on. Finally you'd return the nav element to your calling function.

Your approach with javascript/typescript could be completely different, creating your page & navbar in .html files and using a separate .js (or .ts) file to manipulate the DOM that is built from the html. PHP is processed on the server while JS is processed on the client (in the browser).

As a note, I would not go about this by creating a bunch of random functions and calling them to assemble your html.  Instead, I would create a class for each type of thing you want to render.  When you want to render the page to html, instantiate a Page object, and call that Page object's render method, which will in turn instantiate any objects that it needs to, like NavMenuItem instances, and then these NavMenuItem instances will call their own render methods to convert themselves into html.

Where are you running the script?  Are you generating pages server-side in something like Node.js?  Or client-side?  I highly recommend checking out Web Components, and especially Lit which is a lightweight framework for using them.  It includes a very simple html function which can be used for inserting arbitrary data into your HTML without issues.  https://lit.dev/

@Brad Yes, I am running it through Node.js. I use the command "npm run dev"

You're almost there.
There are a handful of ways to buld DOM Fragments but one way is to repeatedly use:

document.createElement() // to create the element before customising it
myParentElement.appendChild(myElement) // appends the new element to its parent


Working Example


const buildNavbar = () => {

  const menuItems = {
    Home: "index.html",
    About: "about.html",
    FAQ: "faq.html",
    Contact: "contact.html",
  };
  
  // BUILD <nav> ELEMENT
  const navbarNavigation = document.createElement('nav');

  // BUILD <ul> ELEMENT
  const navbarUnorderedList = document.createElement('ul');

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(menuItems)) {

    // BUILD <li> ELEMENT
    const navbarListItem = document.createElement('li');
    
    // BUILD <a> ELEMENT AND APPEND TO <li> ELEMENT
    const navbarAnchor = document.createElement('a');
    navbarAnchor.setAttribute('href', value);
    navbarAnchor.textContent = key;
    navbarListItem.appendChild(navbarAnchor);

    // APPEND <li> ELEMENT TO <ul> ELEMENT
    navbarUnorderedList.appendChild(navbarListItem);
  }
  
  // APPEND <ul> ELEMENT TO <nav> ELEMENT
  navbarNavigation.appendChild(navbarUnorderedList);

  // APPEND <nav> ELEMENT TO <body> ELEMENT
  document.body.appendChild(navbarNavigation);
}

buildNavbar();




N.B. Not uncommonly you'll see approaches which concatenate strings / template literals and then utilise the innerHTML property, something like this:
  const menuItems = {
    Home: "index.html",
    About: "about.html",
    FAQ: "faq.html",
    Contact: "contact.html",
  };

const navbarNavigation = document.createElement('nav');

let navbarNavigationChildren = '<ul>';
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(menuItems)) {
  navbarNavigationChildren += `<li><a href="${value}">${key}</a></li>`;
}
navbarNavigationChildren += '</ul>';

navbarNavigation.innerHTML = navbarNavigationChildren;
document.appendChild(navbarNavigation);

Which is much closer to how you'd approach the issue in PHP.
However, my own experience is that as you get used to creating DOM Nodes and thinking in those terms, the approach where you build a string of markup and append it via .innerHTML loses quite a lot of its appeal.
Although popular, the latter approach is something like building JSON via string concatenation and then converting that string into an object via JSON.parse(), rather than simply... building an object.

I have tried something like this before. It didn't work out for me. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I know it is also possible to make a seperate html file for the navbar and reuse that. The only problem is that I had the idea to make the navbar completely in a function and I can't abandon that idea. I have made some changes to my original comment to show what I have done now.

Do not concatenate arbitrary data into HTML.  Just like in PHP or any other language, doing so risks generating invalid HTML and injecting malicious scripts.

Okay, it works on javascript now, just not when i use typescript. But i will find out myself how I will let that work. At least I know it is not faulty syntax.
